# Find the degree of a finite field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

What is the degree of the extension $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6}):\mathbb{Q}]$?
Is it true that this extension is equal to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{6}$

Comment: Since you haven't done so, I will mention that you can hit the arrows on the top right of an answer to upvote or downvote, depending if you think it is a good answer or not, and if it answers your question, you can hit the green checkmark, right below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[]{2}, \sqrt[]{3}]$ contains $\sqrt[]{6}$ given that its elements must be closed under multiplication and so the product $(0+\sqrt[]{2})(0+\sqrt[]{3})=\sqrt[]{6}$ must be contained in the set. So extending it to $\sqrt[]{6}$ is redundant.

To determine the degree of the extension consider what elements need to be included in the basis so that when our scalars consist of elements from $\mathbb{Q}$, we can get all of the rationals, and any multiple of the elements of the extension so that it is closed under mutliplication and addition.